# Passing in list of optional arguments in R

Tags: r, function, optional-arguments

I am trying to simplify my code by making a list of variables that I can pass into a function as optional arguments. The function has other arguments as well that would be specified directly. For example:

```
foo <- function(data, ..., func = mean, cross_depth = NULL, data_table = FALSE){
what function does here}

varx <- list("var1", "var2", "var3")

foo(data, varx, func = func, data_table = TRUE, cross_depth = 3)
```

The list of optional arguments is always changing, and this function is used repeatedly, so it helps to be able to specify these variables outside of the function itself. I have tried using `do.call` in various ways, but it keeps throwing errors. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use `do.call` i.e. `do.call(foo,  ...` and pass the arguments as a list.  The variadic arguments may be better to be placed at the end in the function so that all other arguments can be passed in the named list

Comment: I think your optional arguments need names if you want to use them in `do.call`: `args <- list(arg1=3, arg2="gotme"); do.call(foo, args)`.

Comment: @Angela: You should post one of your attempts at using `do.call`. Jari is correct to a point. I think his example might fail at the point where there was `data` argument in the list. Naming is a requirement for the values to be matched to elements inside the body. Has nothing to do with do.call, but is rather a requirement buildt into the R parser., although no error will be thrown if some or all fail to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to handle this kind of pattern is to give the function an `extra_args` parameter that accepts an arbitrary list (and defaults to an empty list if you want to ignore it):

```r
foo <- function(data, extra_args = list(), func = mean, 
                cross_depth = NULL, data_table = FALSE) {
  # Do stuff 
}
```

Which allows:

```
varx <- list("var1", "var2", "var3")

foo(data, varx, func = func, data_table = TRUE, cross_depth = 3)
```